# How can I use Mathematica to make a captcha image?

Tags: image-processing

This was inspired by [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/113607/9490) which is about the serious business of website deployment in the Wolfram Cloud, and interaction with Google's reCaptcha system.

I started thinking of how to make those neat (and annoying) images that feature some variant of scrambled text that you have to type in to prove that you are human.

There are plenty of posts on the web about using *Mathematica* to beat captchas via OCR and wavelet transforms, [here](https://www.stthomas.edu/media/centerforappliedmathematics/camreports/Wifvat_CAPTCHA.pdf) is an example.

This is what I've come up with (with a nod to kglr for showing how to grab the [font information](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10047/9490)),

```
fontlist = 
  FE`Evaluate[FEPrivate`GetPopupList["MenuListFonts"]] /. 
   Rule[x_, y_] :> y;
effectslist = ImageEffect[];
captcha := With[{key = RandomChoice[WordList["CommonWords"], 2]},
  Print@StringJoin@Riffle[key, " "];
  With[{font = RandomChoice[fontlist]},
        (Rotate[
            Style[#, FontFamily -> font, RandomColor[]]
            , RandomReal[{-.5, .5}]] &) /@ #] & /@
      (Characters /@
         key) // Grid // Rasterize[#, ImageSize -> 600] & //

   ImageEffect[#, RandomChoice[effectslist]] &
  ]
```

It's limited to applying a different font to two different dictionary words and then giving each letter a random color and orientation, and finally applying an image transformation chosen from a non-exhaustive list.  But I feel like the results are lacking, and they would be very easy to defeat via the methods described above:

[image]

Captchas I see on the web often use a swirling effect, or a rippling effect, and some nonlinear distortions, but I don't know how to do that in *Mathematica*

Comment: One way could be finding the parametric equation of individual alphabets ( [How to create a new “person curve”?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17704/how-to-create-a-new-person-curve) ) and then then distort the outlines with a random number. The `makeFourierSeriesApproximationManipulat` from [Making Formulas… for Everything—From Pi to the Pink Panther to Sir Isaac Newton](http://blog.wolframalpha.com/2013/05/17/making-formulas-for-everything-from-pi-to-the-pink-panther-to-sir-isaac-newton/) can be useful  as well. I never used them, so can't make any more comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is something I tried based on Simon's answer to [How to create a new “person curve”?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17704/how-to-create-a-new-person-curve)

I am starting from a text.

```
pic = Rasterize[Style["Captcha", FontFamily -> "Sans"], ImageSize -> 300] // Image
```

[image]

Now introducing Simon functions

```
param[x_, m_, t_] := Module[{f, n = Length[x], nf}, 
    f = Chop[Fourier[x]][[;; Ceiling[Length[x]/2]]];
    nf = Length[f];
    Total[Rationalize[2 Abs[f]/Sqrt[n] Sin[Pi/2 - Arg[f]
       + 2. Pi Range[0, nf - 1] t], .01][[;; Min[m, nf]]]]]

tocurve[Line[data_], m_, t_] := param[#, m, t] & /@ Transpose[data]

lines = Cases[Normal@ListContourPlot[Reverse@ImageData[img], 
          Contours -> {0.5}], _Line, -1];
```

Evaluating this with 25 modes gives you

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[tocurve[#, 25, t] & /@ lines], {t, 0, 1}, 
   Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Lets add some additional distortion.

```
modes = 7;
distort[t_] := 20 Cos[t]
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[(tocurve[#, modes, t] + distort[t]) & /@ lines],
 {t, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

You can always find a function which will give you better distortion. For better result you can play with separate alphabets and rotate or displace them as you wish.

To add more spice you can use `ImageTransformation`. Actually you can directly use it to your captha in the beginning. For example lets try the last part of your image

[image]

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UlVv.png"] 

f[x_, y_] := {x + 10 Sin[.05 x], y + 5 Sin[.1 y]}
ImageTransformation[img, f @@ # &, DataRange -> Full]
```

[image]

And again, you can define any transformation function (`f[x_,y_]`) you want.

Comment: That image looks great!