# Captcha text morphing effect

Tags: image-processing, image

There have been many posts about generating and cracking Captchas. However, I have never seen a post or answer concerning one the more recent versions of re-captcha images - a "word morphing effect" that looks like this:

[image]

It seems to follow random sinusoidals with random magnifying glass effects here and there, making some parts of the glyphs look bulbous or shrunken in places.

How can I make this with MMA?

**Related:**

-[How can I use Mathematica to make a captcha image?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/113644/how-can-i-use-mathematica-to-make-a-captcha-image)

Comment: Are you interested in reproducing this particular effect, or any human-readable morphing effect would do?

Comment: Need something like this one

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is one way of doing this. I am mostly inspired by (repeating code from) [`ImageTransformation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageTransformation.html).

Since the "fish-eye" transformation is somewhat capricious and not that intuitive, at the end I just generated random captcha images with multiple random sequences of random fish-eye lenses. (Hopefully one of those random images is satisfactory enough...)

```
pic = Image[Rasterize[Style["381057", FontFamily -> "Sans"], ImageSize -> 300]];
pic = ColorConvert[pic, "Grayscale"]
```

[image]

```
pic2 = ImageTransformation[pic, # + {0, RandomReal[{0.02, 0.04}] (1.6 Cos[ 6 Norm[#]] + Sin[ 20 #[[1]]])} &, Padding -> 100]
```

[image]

```
pic3 = ImageTransformation[pic2, RotationTransform[\[Pi]/6], 
  Padding -> 100, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
Clear[MyLens]
MyLens[s_] := 
  Function[{pt}, 
    Block[{r, a},
      r = Norm[pt - s]^2/Norm[s]; a = (ArcTan @@ (pt - s));
      s + r {Cos[a], Sin[a]}]
  ];

Clear[FishEyeEffect]
FishEyeEffect[img_, lens_] := 
  ColorNegate[
   ImageCrop[
    ImageTransformation[
     ImagePad[ColorNegate[img], {{100, 100}, {150, 150}}], lens]]];

SeedRandom[33221]
randomLensFuncs = 
  Table[MyLens /@ RandomReal[{0, 1}, {RandomInteger[{1, 3}], 2}], {i, 10}];
Length /@ randomLensFuncs

(* {3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2} *)

AbsoluteTiming[
 pics = Flatten[
    FoldList[FishEyeEffect, RandomChoice[{pic2, pic3}], #] & /@ 
     randomLensFuncs];
 ]

(* {60.8328, Null} *)

Multicolumn[pics, 6]
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer as always

Comment: @M.R. Thanks! I am glad it fits what you are looking for.